Spousal Visa in Netherlands - Work permit in Denmark?
I have received a spousal visa with my husband to be in the Netherlands.  My employer is looking for me to work the majority of the time in Denmark under a Danish work visa.
Would taking this up invalidate my Dutch spousal visa?

The normal process in Schengen countries is for the visa to be replaced by a residence permit.  Have you done that?  What sort of schedule do you anticipate for "a majority of time"?  Have you investigated the tax implications of this arrangement?  Do you have a specific reason to want to keep a Dutch visa or residence permit if you are not in fact residing there?  Is your husband an EU, EEA, or Swiss citizen?  Is your husband a Dutch national?
